# What is the benefit of Flux.groupBy? vs list partition?

Tags: kotlin, spring-webflux, project-reactor

Trying to understand the benefit of grouping by directly on the Flux, as opposed to collecting all element and then grouping them by using the Java stream function groupingBy (or Kotlin `partition` like in the following example).

Here are 2 examples:
First with `groupBy` and second with `partition`.
I am trying to get a sense of when to use what.

```
    @Test
    fun groupByTwoLists() {
        val numbers = (0..9).toList()

        Flux.fromIterable(numbers)
            .groupBy<Boolean> { it % 2 == 0 }
            .flatMap { group: GroupedFlux<Boolean, Int> ->
                if (group.key() == true) {
                    group.collectList().doOnNext { println("We are even") }
                } else {
                    group.collectList().doOnNext { println("We are odd") }
                }
            }
            .test()
            .expectNextCount(2)
            .verifyComplete()
    }

    @Test
    fun partitionLists() {
        val numbers = (0..9).toList()
        val (even, odd) = numbers.partition { it % 2 == 0 }

        val monoEven = Mono.just(even).doOnNext { println("We are even") }
        val monoOdd = Mono.just(odd).doOnNext { println("We are odd") }

        Flux.merge(monoEven, monoOdd)
            .test()
            .expectNextCount(2)
            .verifyComplete()
    }
```

Comment: `partition()` is a `List` method, while `groupBy()` is a method of `Flux`, so I'd say that the former is a good thing to use when you're working on a `List`, and the latter is good when you're working on a `Flux`. They're not really even comparable - `Flux.groupBy(...)` is more like `list.stream().collect(groupingBy(...))`, in that it can collect into more than two groups.

Comment: `partition()` is a special case of `list.stream().collect(groupingBy(...))` with only 2 groups. Since every `Flux` can be collected into a list and then grouped by, I am trying to get what is the benefit of grouping by the `Flux` vs collecting into a list and then grouping the list.

Comment: a list has a defined length, a flux has no defined length as it is a stream of undefined length. So from a memory standpoint a flux is better

Answer (score 1):

I understand the difference now.

The Flux of Fluxes (created by the `Flux.groupBy`) is good when you have a flow that you want to process differently for each group. It allows you to do things like `publishOn` a `Scheduler`. You might want to use different `Scheduler` per each on of the types you grouped by.

The 2 tests I gave in the original question are not a good example because I am using a finite list of numbers and not a flow of data.

Here is a nice example of using the `Flux.groupBy` https://levelup.gitconnected.com/creating-a-flux-of-fluxes-with-project-reactors-group-by-method-37200bfc2a.